# What kind of license/copyright is this? Can I use this in a GPLv3 licensed project?

Tags: licensing, gpl, copyright

I intent to release my code under the GPLv3 license. No problem to do this, until I came upon a 3rd party file. Their owners have the following statement in it (and no other statement regarding copyrights/licensing)

```
Copyright (c) B.J. Frey & D. Dueck (2006). This software may be
freely used and distributed for non-commercial purposes.
```

The file can be retrieved from http://www.psi.toronto.edu/affinitypropagation/software/apcluster.m

I haven't modified it and it is only a small (but vital) part of my project.
Can I proceed to apply the GPLv3 license to it? What kind of license does this file have?

Comment: Assuming you're not using third party GPL libraries, you could use a classpath exception for this library in your software.

Comment: So the 3rd party file cannot be used and distributed freely for **commercial** purposes? Then it is not GPL compatible. You can ask, however, the authors if they allow you to put that file under GPL. Contact information of Prof. Frey is easily found by Google, see http://www.psi.toronto.edu/~frey/

Comment: The authors should provide a statement (if they agree) and I can license this part under GPLv3 under their name I guess. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I proceed to apply the GPLv3 license to it?

No. The GPLv3 forbids any usage restrictions, this license has a usage restriction. Whichever way you try to resolve this conflict, you will violate one of the two licenses.

> What kind of license does this file have?

Its license is:

> This software may be freely used and distributed for non-commercial purposes.

Comment: So, its license has not any particular name, yet this statement describes what I can do as would do a license. Am I correct?

Comment: This statement *is* the license.